# Multiprocessing Pool does not seem to process in parallel, time scales linearly with number of inputs

Tags: python, jupyter, python-multiprocessing

I have a Python function that runs by itself in a little over 3 minutes. I want to run it hundreds of times to generate a statistical sample of the results. So I am using the `multiprocessing` module in juypter to run multiple instances of the same function at the same time. Here is my code

```
def my_func(filename):
    "Takes filename as input"
    "Process and clean and generate random test/train splits"
    "Run ML Classification algorithms"

    return results
```

I then use the `multiprocessing` model in jupyter

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    filename = []
    for i in range(0,2):
        filename.append(fname)
    results = pool.map(my_func, filename)
```

In the above example the array filename just contains the name of the file twice that I want the function to run. This takes about 4 minutes to run. (2 minute per instance which is for some reason better than around 3 minutes per instance for the standalone function)

If now I change the filename to have 4 input files (i.e. filename = [fname, fname, fname, fname]) then the whole process takes 8 minutes to run (again 2 minutes per instance). This just seems to scale linearly as I increase my input and is not scaling as it would if it were processing the functions in parallel. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I am using jupyter on a mac with the M1 chip if it matters.

Comment: Multiprocessing is not going reduce I/O time.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the reply. My understanding was that multiprocessing will run all the instances at the same time on different cores. So the total time to run 4 instances should be equivalent to that of running a single instance of the function.

Comment: If your processing was pure CPU and you had at least 2 processors (which you do), then you would expect to have complete parallelization and both "jobs" would complete in 2 minutes. But there is also I/O involved and you only have one (1) I/O processor, i.e. disk drive and disk controller and so there will not be perfect parallelization of I/O. It's difficult to predict the results since you are going against the same file with both jobs. It might depend on the disk's design, whether caching is done, etc.

Comment: @Booboo thank you. It was pure CPU I believe.  I think only 2 processors available is the most plausible explanation for scaling. Do you know how I can make more processors available since the Mac is supposed to have a 8 core CPU? I tried changing the argument of Pool() like Pool(4) but it didn't really help.

Comment: @AkshayGhalsasi You say it is pure CPU with filenames as the arguments? It sounded to me like you were passing input filenames because you were processing files. If your actual `my_func` is not unreasonably large, now might be a good time to post it. Also, try printing out `os.cpu_count()` to find out how many processors you have..

Comment: @Booboo The output of `os.cpu_count` is 8. `my_func()` is a little large but it takes in the data from filename, splits it randomly into train/test data and then runs some standard ML classification algorithms on it and aggregates the results. Thanks